# Fechar webcam com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o plugin [Photobooth](http://wolframhempel.github.io/photobooth-js/)  para capturar imagem da webcam pelo nevegador, mas depois de permitir o uso da webcam pelo browser e fazer a captura em uma modal eu fecho a modal e a webcam continua em uso. Alguém sabe como fechar a webcam pelo jQuery? pois na documentação do plugin eu não encontrei essa opção.

Comment: Eu também estou querendo descobrir a mesma coisa, porém quero fazer no javascript "puro"

Comment: Nunca fiz esse tipo de trabalho, mas por acaso ao fechar a modal você poderia chamar um plugin que fechasse a cam. 
Existe um tutorial explicando o uso do plugin, talvez tenha a função que desejas. http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/04/jquery-webcam-photobooth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verifiquei direito na documentação e percebi que tem o método 
pause() que serve para parar o uso da webcam, então resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on('click','#get-photo',function(){
        $modal.close();
        $('#capiture-image').data("photobooth").pause();
});
```